# How to move a index from one index node to anther index node in couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I have 6 index nodes in couchbase cluster. I would like to replace once index node and move indexes from old index node to new index node. What is best practice for moving indexes from once node to another ?

Answer (score 2):

In Couchbase 5.5, you can use the ALTER INDEX statement to move an index from one node to another. Couchbase 5.5 will be released within a couple of weeks.

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/alterindex.html

Comment: a) 5.5 was released today.
b) for older releases i would recommend either to drop-recreate or to use move-index api, for more info refer to this blog: https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-index-replicas/