# Move Indexes and Users from Couchbase 5.1 to Couchbase 6.0

Tags: couchbase

There was a question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417008/how-to-move-a-index-from-one-index-node-to-anther-index-node-in-couchbase) that's similar but does not solve my trouble.

I am running a Couchbase 5.1 server and would like to transfer EVERYTHING to a newly created Couchbase 6.0 server. Documents and Views have transferred as expected, but the primary and global secondary indexes have not been transferred as should have been according to Couchbase documentation [here(for cbbackup_5.1)](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.1/cli/cbbackup-tool.html) and [here(for cbrestore_6.0)](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/cli/cbrestore-tool.html). Both clusters are single node.

The commands used are:

./cbbackup http://source_IP:8091 ~/backups -u Username -p Password

./cbrestore ~/backups http://dest_IP:8091 -b Bucketname -u Username -p Password

::restore command run multiple times to cover multiple buckets

::received positive success messages in all cases.

The number of indexes are so many that re-creating each would be a major bother, and version 5.1 did not have the Alter Index capability.

Plus, any way to transfer users too? I have failed to find any documentation on this.

Comment: Can you also add the command you are running?

Comment: done. anything more I could add?